# How do I exclude .NetStandard dll dependencies when building for .Net framework?

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have added multi-framework build output to the csproj:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net461</TargetFrameworks>
```

but when it builds for .net framework, it adds all the .NetStandard dependencies as well, which aren't needed. How do I exclude them?

Comment: What do you mean it adds the .Net standard dependencies? You mean in the build output of the netstandard2.0?